# magento - Image type and information need to be specified for each store view

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing, magento

I have a working Magento 1.4.1.0 installation that is due to go live next week, all was well until yesterday when I noticed the following message when uploading images to a product '*Image type and information need to be specified for each store view'*. The image uploads fine and is visible on my server, the preview works when I hover over it too.

But when I attempt to load the product on the front-end the template breaks in places and when I view the source the img `src=""` is blank?

Two things I played around with before I noticed it wasn't working were image watermarks and attribute sets, could this be a factor?

I have searched the Magento forums but cannot find a solution that works..

I have tried the following to fix it... Installing the dull uploading to replace the flash one, tweaking the `.htaccess` and `php.ini`, flushing the cache and indexes.

I am at a total loss and have a fast approaching deadline.

Please can someone help?

Thanks Dan

Comment: If any solution found please share it on forum.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, later I found that this notice was normal, but the custom image used to watermark the product images was very large, so the small images were not visible.

I removed the watermark image and cleared the image cache form cache management, after that when I refreshed the catalog, all images were visible without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your import file for images, make sure you include a "store" column (or is it "_store"?), and put the correct value in that column. I've had the same problem and I believe that's how I solved it.

Comment: I just realized this question is 2 years old. Not sure why it popped up.

Answer (score 0):

With me this problem happened when I newly created Store using Menu **Admin->System-> Manage Store**.

In the same menu, I clicked on the **"Default Store View"** to edit its properties and disabled it.  The problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing `php5-gd` on my server. After the install I manage to upload the images.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

then restart  your web server

Comment: On CentOS, this will be `php-gd`. The above answer is for Ubuntu/Debian